# Python return tuple in threading

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, queue, python-decorators

I got stuck with a sticky problem with threading in python. Here is what I have.
At first, I have a decorator which I used for every function to get two values, time and result. After I get those numbers I used python logging to store time.
Now I want to run two functions at the same time and get those values.
Which is the simplest way to do that?

Decorator:

```
def my_dec(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
        result = func(*arg)
        end_time  = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
        time = end_time - start_time
        return time, result
    return wrapper
```

Function1:

```
@my_dec
def get_taskbar_tooltip_message(timeout=10):
    #This function calls another functions which waits and return value at a given timeout
    #Returns string
```

Function2:

```
@my_dec
def check_pis(timer=200, status="start"):
     #This function also calls other functions, which takes some time
     #Returns bool
```

Comment: I don't see you easily incorporating the multiprocessing of two functions into this existing decorator in a general way *if* that is what you are considering. So the simplest approach is to just learn about multiprocessing and then treat the decorated functions like any other functions you want to run in parallel -- but you have to take an initial attempt at this. As an aside: shouldn't that be `result = func(*args)`? Better yet: `def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):` and then `result = func(*args, **kwargs)`. And your first statement of function `my_dec` should be `functools.wraps(func)`.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to run two functions at the same time and get those values.

You could start by trying out the high level tools from the standard library's [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures) module.

**Multiprocessing** is the *real* parallel processing:

```
import time
from functools import wraps
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as Executor

def my_dec(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.perf_counter()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.perf_counter()
        return end - start, result
    return wrapper

@my_dec
def get_taskbar_tooltip_message(timeout=10):
    time.sleep(3)
    return "a string"

@my_dec
def check_pis(timer=200, status="start"):
    time.sleep(5)
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":

    with Executor() as exec:
        start = time.perf_counter()
        result_1 = exec.submit(get_taskbar_tooltip_message)
        result_2 = exec.submit(check_pis)
        print(result_1.result(), result_2.result())
        end = time.perf_counter()
        print(end - start)
```

A couple of remarks:

- I replaced `datetime.datetime.now()` with `time.perf_counter()` which seems better suited to the task at hand.
- As pointed out by @Booboo: Using [`wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) is good practice. And it's rather important here: Without it the multiprocessing would fail (due to an unpickling error).
- I have enlarged the `wrapper` signature with `**kwargs` in case of keyword arguments (also pointed out by @Booboo).

**Threading** looks similar, just use another type of `Executor`:

```
import time
from functools import wraps
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as Executor

...

with Executor() as exec:
    start = time.perf_counter()
    result_1 = exec.submit(get_taskbar_tooltip_message)
    result_2 = exec.submit(check_pis)
    print(result_1.result(), result_2.result())
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(end - start)
```

Here the `if __name__ == "__main__":` isn't necessary. Threading doesn't break out of the current process, so it's not *real* parallel, but it is still extremely useful.

What kind of concurrency approach to choose depends on your use case: Multiprocessing is better for cpu-heavy tasks, whereas threading might be better for i/o-heavy tasks. (Python also offers more lower level interfaces for both, [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).) If you're looking at i/o-heavy tasks then there's another approach available, [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html), which might be an alternative: There's a bit of a learning curve, and you might have to restructure your functions, but it might be worth the effort.